# Remove Text From Background

Tags: color, gimp, text, background

How can i remove the text from background of this image using gimp?

[image]

The text is composed by different colors so i cannot use "color exchange" option for every single color of the text.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you asking how to remove the "PREVIEW" watermark? I assume whoever added it doesn't want you to use the image. Is the image copyright? If so, sorry but I won't help.

Comment: It may be that recreating the background is much faster than removing the text.

Comment: Related: [Is there an accepted way to ask how to remove a watermark?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/is-there-an-accepted-way-to-ask-how-to-remove-a-watermark)

Comment: BillyKerr That file is the summary of my university career and I find disconcerting to have to pay for it. Peace.

Comment: @FlyBob - then why don't you just type it out again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deceptively simple. The orange color of the text is 100% red, 78% green, and 0% blue, and the rest of the image is black or white. So making a monochrome image from the red channel alone is enough. For this use `Color>Components>Channel mixer`, set to "Monochrome", and use Red=100%, Green=Blue=0%.

Comment: Then accept the answer :)